# How to create seconds object with new operator

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to create 2 class objects with operator *new*, but when im trying to create a new one it says that the second one was not declared and if I change interface to something else it also gives an error.

```
void Game::start(){
    // clear the screen
    scene->clear();

    //player1 = new Player("Player 1");
    //player2 = new Player("Player 2");
    player = new Player("Player1");

    interface = new Interface();
    interface2 = new Interface();
    //Interface interface;
    interface->placeCombatColumn();
    //interface.placeCombatColumn();
    drawGUI();
    interface->placeCombat();

}
```

Errors:

- player was not declared in this scope
- interface2 was not declared in this scope

Comment: Please show games instance variables.

Comment: Sorry but im new with programming and im not sure if i know what instance variables are :/

Comment: Variables declare in the class

Comment: By founding them i realized where was my mistake... I had only "interface" declared there. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok please upvote my comment

Answer (score 1):

You should have a (possibly) private member

```
Player * player;
```

in your class, like this:

```
class Game {

public:
  void start();

private:
  Player * player;

};
```

This way, you can refer to the variable `player` from inside your `Game` class methods (all of them, including `start()`). Same apply to other variables, like `interface`.

If you need a variable to be local to a method, instead (i.e. you don't need it outside the method *scope*) you have to declare it, at least when assigning a value to it, inside the method:

```
void Game::start() {

    // clear the screen
    scene->clear();

    Player * player = new Player("Player1");

...
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for sharing.